# Why is calling vector.reserve(required + 1) faster than vector.reserve(required)?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, stdvector

I am doing some tests measuring the performance of standard containers under various conditions, and I came across something odd. When I am inserting many items into the middle of a `std::vector`, if I first call reserve with the exact number of elements that I will be adding, I see essentially no performance difference in most circumstances compared with not calling reserve, which is surprising. More surprising, however, is that if I call reserve with the exact number of elements I need `+ 1`, then I get a significant performance improvement. This is a sample table of results that I just got (all time are in seconds):

```
+---------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| # of elements | vector | vector (reserved) | vector (reserved + 1) |
+---------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|         10000 | 0.04   | 0.04              | 0.03                  |
|         20000 | 0.14   | 0.14              | 0.11                  |
|         30000 | 0.32   | 0.32              | 0.25                  |
|         40000 | 0.55   | 0.55              | 0.44                  |
|         50000 | 0.87   | 0.85              | 0.66                  |
|         60000 | 1.24   | 1.24              | 0.96                  |
|         70000 | 1.69   | 1.68              | 1.31                  |
|         80000 | 2.17   | 2.21              | 1.71                  |
|         90000 | 2.78   | 2.75              | 2.16                  |
|        100000 | 3.43   | 3.44              | 2.68                  |
|        110000 | 4.13   | 4.15              | 3.23                  |
|        120000 | 4.88   | 4.89              | 3.86                  |
|        130000 | 5.79   | 5.8               | 4.51                  |
|        140000 | 6.71   | 6.71              | 5.24                  |
|        150000 | 7.7    | 7.7               | 6.02                  |
|        160000 | 8.76   | 8.67              | 6.86                  |
|        170000 | 9.9    | 9.91              | 7.74                  |
|        180000 | 11.07  | 10.98             | 8.64                  |
|        190000 | 12.34  | 12.35             | 9.64                  |
|        200000 | 13.64  | 13.56             | 10.72                 |
|        210000 | 15.1   | 15.04             | 11.67                 |
|        220000 | 16.59  | 16.41             | 12.89                 |
|        230000 | 18.05  | 18.06             | 14.13                 |
|        240000 | 19.64  | 19.74             | 15.36                 |
|        250000 | 21.34  | 21.17             | 16.66                 |
|        260000 | 23.08  | 23.06             | 18.02                 |
|        270000 | 24.87  | 24.89             | 19.42                 |
|        280000 | 26.5   | 26.58             | 20.9                  |
|        290000 | 28.51  | 28.69             | 22.4                  |
|        300000 | 30.69  | 30.74             | 23.97                 |
|        310000 | 32.73  | 32.81             | 25.57                 |
|        320000 | 34.63  | 34.99             | 27.28                 |
|        330000 | 37.12  | 37.17             | 28.99                 |
|        340000 | 39.36  | 39.43             | 30.83                 |
|        350000 | 41.7   | 41.48             | 32.45                 |
|        360000 | 44.11  | 44.22             | 34.55                 |
|        370000 | 46.62  | 46.71             | 36.22                 |
|        380000 | 49.09  | 48.91             | 38.46                 |
|        390000 | 51.71  | 51.98             | 40.22                 |
|        400000 | 54.45  | 54.56             | 43.03                 |
|        410000 | 57.23  | 57.29             | 44.84                 |
|        420000 | 60     | 59.73             | 46.67                 |
|        430000 | 62.9   | 63.03             | 49.3                  |
+---------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I checked the implementation, and it doesn't appear to have an off-by-one error. I then further tested by printing the size and the capacity immediately after calling reserve, and then I printed them again after filling up the vector, and everything looks good.

```
before:
    size: 0
    capacity: 10000
after:
    size: 10000
    capacity: 10000

before:
    size: 0
    capacity: 20000
after:
    size: 20000
    capacity: 20000

...
```

Compiler is gcc 4.7.2 on Fedora Linux x86_64. Compiler options are `-std=c++11 -Ofast -march=native -funsafe-loop-optimizations -flto=4 - fwhole-program`

The code is below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/timer.hpp>

namespace {
constexpr size_t array_size = 1;

unsigned number() {
        static std::random_device rd;
        static std::mt19937 random_engine(rd());
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> distribution(0, std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
        return distribution(random_engine);
}

class Class {
        public:
                Class() {
                        x[0] = number();
                }
                std::string to_string() const {
                        return std::to_string(x[0]);
                }
                inline friend bool operator<=(Class const & lhs, Class const & rhs) {
                        return lhs.x[0] <= rhs.x[0];
                }
        private:
                std::array<uint32_t, array_size> x;
};

template<typename Container>
void add(Container & container, Class const & value) {
        auto const it = std::find_if(std::begin(container), std::end(container), [&](Class const & c) {
                return value <= c;
        });
        container.emplace(it, value);
}

// Do something with the result
template<typename Container>
void insert_to_file(Container const & container) {
        std::fstream file("file.txt");
        for (auto const & value : container) {
                file << value.to_string() << '\n';
        }
}

template<typename Container>
void f(std::vector<Class> const & values) {
        Container container;
        container.reserve(values.size());
        for (auto const & value : values) {
                add(container, value);
        }
        insert_to_file(container);
}

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        std::size_t const size = (argc == 1) ? 1 : std::stoul(argv[1]);
        // Default constructor of Class fills in values here
        std::vector<Class> const values_to_be_copied(size);
        typedef std::vector<Class> Container;
        boost::timer timer;
        f<Container>(values_to_be_copied);
        std::cerr << "Finished in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds.\n";
}
```

I created a C++03 version to try and help other people reproduce it, but I cannot reproduce it in this version, despite trying to make it show the problem by making it as direct of a translation as possible:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

namespace {
unsigned number() {
        static boost::random::mt19937 random_engine;
        static boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<boost::uint32_t> distribution(0, std::numeric_limits<boost::uint32_t>::max());
        return distribution(random_engine);
}

class Class {
        public:
                Class() {
                        x[0] = number();
                }
                inline friend bool operator<=(Class const & lhs, Class const & rhs) {
                        return lhs.x[0] <= rhs.x[0];
                }
                std::string to_string() const {
                        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x[0]);
                }
        private:
                boost::array<boost::uint32_t, 1> x;
};

class Less {
public:
        Less(Class const & c):
                value(c) {
        }
        bool operator()(Class const & c) const {
                return value <= c;
        }
private:
        Class value;
};

void add(std::vector<Class> & container, Class const & value) {
        std::vector<Class>::iterator it = std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), Less(value));
        container.insert(it, value);
}

// Do something with the result
void insert_to_file(std::vector<Class> const & container) {
        std::fstream file("file.txt");
        for (std::vector<Class>::const_iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it) {
                file << it->to_string() << '\n';
        }
}

void f(std::vector<Class> const & values) {
        std::vector<Class> container;
        container.reserve(values.size() + 1);
        for (std::vector<Class>::const_iterator it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it) {
                add(container, *it);
        }
        insert_to_file(container);
}

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        std::size_t const size = (argc == 1) ? 1 : boost::lexical_cast<std::size_t>(argv[1]);
        // Default constructor of Class fills in values here
        std::vector<Class> const values_to_be_copied(size);
        boost::timer timer;
        f(values_to_be_copied);
        std::cerr << "Finished in " << timer.elapsed() << " seconds.\n";
}
```

The line that currently calls reserve was changed to include a `+ 1` or was completely removed, depending on which test I was running. The entire thing was run from a shell script that started at 10000 elements and increased up to 430000 elements, going one version at a time.

My processor is an Intel i5 4-core processor, and I have 4 GiB of memory. I will try and simplify the C++11 version of the code as much as possible to see if I can isolate the problem.

Does anyone know why reserving one more element than I need is causing this increase in speed?

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot reproduce using gcc 4.7.2 on OSX x86_64 (same compiler options except that I had to remove `-march=native`).

Comment: Have you tried some other sizes other than those round numbers?

Comment: @Mysticial: I'll try with some 'weird' numbers and post my results

Comment: I find it stranger that reserving the correct size has no statistical effect on performance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using gcc 4.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.10, 64bit, same compiler options. All 3 variants (no reserve, correct size, correct size + 1) result in 1.9 seconds for 100k elements. We're talking about line 57, right?

Comment: Has *anyone* here been able to reproduce this? Please shout if you have.

Comment: @NPE I can't even get it to compile. My GCC is too old and MSVC is barfing all over it.

Comment: I'll see if I can get rid of some of the C++11 features without changing the performance characteristics so that people can use other compilers and still get it to work, as well.

Comment: I got it to compile on MSVC by stripping out some of the C++11. No repro. Identical times for me.

Comment: When I changed it to test with steps of 10007 (prime number) up to a maximum of 430301, I got essentially the same results. My final numbers were 63.26 seconds for `vector`, 63.42 seconds for `vector` reserved normally, and 49.51 seconds for `vector` reserved with one additional element.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised no one else can reproduce this. Perhaps it's a processor-specific thing? That's the only thing I can think of that would cause this.

Comment: try it with another compiler(linux:g++/clang , win VC++/MingGw(can be super easy dled -link at isocpp.ort)), provide entire exact source...

Comment: Just a stupid idea: Try to reserve size + 1, but then add one initial element, like a zero. So the vector ends up having all reserved elements filled, but the original vector has one less. I can't explain why this should make a difference compared to the reserve size version, but nobody can explain some behavior here... ;)

Comment: Also, try to exclude the `insert_to_file` from time measuring. Or replace it with a summation of the values and print them on standard output.

Comment: Reproduced, FC18, `g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)`, AMD Phenom II 1100T, so it's not a CPU thing.

Comment: And the problem disappears (`reserve()` becomes as fast as `reserve(+1)`) if I drop the LTO flag. Might be a GCC bug, but I really don't know enough about LTO to investigate.

Comment: I am also on FC18, so perhaps there's something there? I also noticed something interesting: when I default initialize the `std::mt19937` engine instead of using `std::random_device`, then all three versions perform almost identically. When I keep the `std::random_device` initialization but first log all of the initial data to a file (prior to starting the timer), then I get the same times for no reserve as I was before, but now reserve + 1 gives me the same as no reserve, and reserve(exact) gives me the same speed up that reserve + 1 was giving.

Comment: @TC1 And when I turn off lto with the initial logging included, I get the same results I was getting originally (fast reserve + 1, slow other two)...

Comment: @DavidStone FYI, stumbled upon this [Phoronix article about LTO](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gcc_471_lto&num=1) while trying to find any causes. Apparently, GCC LTO can have these kinds of effects. From what I've gathered, short of debugging GCC itself, there's no *comfortable* way of getting to the bottom of this. The generated ASM is practically identical if you don't take the LTO headers into account.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I made the following modification to the program:

```
size_t a = getenv("A") ? 1 : 0;

void f(std::vector<Class> const & values) {
    ...
    container.reserve(values.size() + a);
    ...
}
```

Now the performance is same (fast) regardless if a is 0 or 1. The conclusion must be that the reservation of an extra item has no performance impact (which was assumed in the question). Also other small changes to the source code or compiler flags toggles the performance between fast and slow, so it looks like the code optimizer just has better luck in some cases than in others.

The following implementation of f() triggers the opposite behaviour with same compiler flags, thus it is fast when exact size is reserved and slow when an extra item is reserved:

```
template<typename Container>
void f(std::vector<Class> const & values) {
    Container container;
    container.reserve(values.size());
    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it) {
        add(container, *it);
    }
    insert_to_file(container);
}
```

Comment: -1, this doesn't answer the question or even contribute toward a reasonable explanation.

Comment: It rules out the previous explanations. (a) The observed behaviour is not dependent on the actual reserved size. (b) It is not dependent on LTO being used or not.

Comment: Looks like a mismatching cost model for intel processors. Compile with -march=corei7 and the reserve +1 version will run faster, but only when run on core2. But both binaries will run with same performance on AMD. Compile with -march=k8 and it will be even faster when run on corei7 and not dependent on details such as +1 to reserve.

Comment: This is actually an ingenious proof and it **does** answer the question: The one addition element does nothing. This answer is under-appreciated by far.

Comment: I think this is strong enough evidence to report an optimization bug to the gcc team. Now I just have to figure out why Visual Studio 2012 (with the array_size declared `const` instead of `constexpr` so it compiles) gives me the same performance with `reserve` vs. without, but much worse performance with `reserve` + 1... Either way, it seems that people don't use `reserve` often enough for compiler writers to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference between `reserve` of exact size vs one extra item in your specific case is absolutely negligible. Moreover, some implementations may truncate the requested size to some number (such as power of 2), hence there'll be no difference at all.

OTOH the performance bottleneck of your program seems to be something else. You perform two expensive array operations:

- Search for the appropriate place for an element insertion
- Insert a single element "in the middle"

As you probably noticed, your program depends on `random`. It's easy to see that in your specific case if random numbers are growing - your program will run faster, OTOH if they shrink - you'll have to perform more "expensive" insertions.

I guess that subtle code changes may trigger different random number generation.

Comment: 1) The change is far from negligible, it's 15-20%. 2) The problem shows up when you enable LTO, which suggests that GCC messes up in that part. The fact that it's hard to reproduce (seeing as both versions it showed up on were Fedora 18, GCC 4.7.2) might hint toward it being a bug in that particular version / build, however.

Comment: "Ceiling" of requested size may occur, but not truncation, since the implementation must guarantee that no further allocation occurs until the reserved size is reached.